# Why does fdisk show sda, sdf and sdg but seems to skip sdb, sdc, sdd and sde in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

It is my understanding that Linux will list hard drives using alphabetical ordering and partitions as numbers. On a machine I am working on there are 3 drives but fdisk lists them as `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdf` and `/dev/sdg`.

Why is `fdisk` skipping `b` through `e`?

**EDIT:** The underlying OS is Windows 7 and this output is from a live boot ubuntu disc I had. Also, here is an image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most likely is that someone first added disks `sdf` & `sdg`, then removed/unplugged `sdb`–`sde`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have edited my original post to clarify the situation. The OS is Windows 7 and since it wouldn't boot I loaded a live version of ubuntu to get some diagnostic info.